# Writing data from an API to a CSV

Tags: python, api, csv, python-requests, dataset

Basically I have this code that is working for me and its purpose is to download an entire series from an API about how many times a stock ticker is mentioned on the wallstreetbets sub.

This is the code:

```
import requests

tickers = open("ticker_list.txt","r")
for ticker in tickers:
    ticker = ticker.strip()
    url = "https://XXX SENSIBLE INFO/historical/wallstreetbets/"+ticker
    headers = {'XXX (SENSIBLE INFO'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```

Where the file .txt is a simple list with about 8000 stock simbols.

I show you what are the first lines of the output, just for an example:

```
b'[{"Date": "2018-08-10", "Ticker": "AA", "Mentions": 1}, {"Date": "2018-08-28", "Ticker": "AA", "Mentions": 1}, {"Date": "2018-09-07", "Ticker": "AA", "Mentions": 1}, etc...
b'[{"Date": "2020-12-07", "Ticker": "AACQ", "Mentions": 1}, {"Date": "2020-12-08", "Ticker": "AACQ", "Mentions": 1}, {"Date": "2020-12-22", "Ticker": "AACQ", "Mentions": 1},... etc...
b'[{"Date": "2018-08-08", "Ticker": "AAL", "Mentions": 1}, {"Date": "2018-08-20", "Ticker": "AAL", "Mentions": 1}, {"Date": "2018-09-11", "Ticker": "AAL", "Mentions": 1}, .... etc
```

What I want to do now is to store all the data in a csv file so that the resulting table would be interpreted like this:

|  | AA | AACQ | AAL | ...... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2018 | 3 | 3 | 7 | ... |
| 2/1/2018 | 45 | 89 | 3 | .... |
| 3/1/2018 | 21 | 4 | 2 | ...... |
| .... |  |  |  |  |

(where the numbers in the middle represents the mentions per date per ticker, in this case to simplify I just put random numbers but they need to be the same numbers i got on the output as "mentions")

*Alternatively, if it's easier, I need to create a single csv file for every ticker with the date in the first column and the numbers of mentions in the second column*

Answer (score 0):

The data that is being returned from the site is in JSON format, so this could be converted into a Python data structure using `r.json()`. Next, two things will help you here. Firstly a `Counter` can be used to keep track of all of the `Mentions` in your json data, and a `defaultdict` can be used to build a per date entry for each ticker. The set `all_tickers` can be used to keep track of all the tickers seen in the data and then be used to form the header for your output CSV file.

For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import csv

dates = defaultdict(Counter)
all_tickers = set()
tickers = open("ticker_list.txt")

for ticker in tickers:
    ticker = ticker.strip()
    url = f"https://XXX SENSIBLE INFO/historical/wallstreetbets/{ticker}"
    headers = {'XXX (SENSIBLE INFO'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    
    for row in r.json():
        all_tickers.add(row['Ticker'])
        date = datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d')   # convert to datetime format
        dates[date][row['Ticker']] += row['Mentions']

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=['Date', *sorted(all_tickers)])
    csv_output.writeheader()
    
    for date, values in sorted(dates.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
        row = {'Date' : date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')}      # Create an output date format of day/month/year
        row.update(values)
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This should produce the output you need.